# How to select multiple objects of a class for css manipulation

Tags: php, jquery, css

This might be a simple question or something that isn't possible. I'm trying to use the querySelector() function to select objects of a particular class for css manipulation. I've got several objects of different classes and am using links in my main navigation to toggle objects depending on which link is clicked.

I'm using a combination of php and jQuery here to accomplish this.

This is what works for a single object:

The php/HTML:

```
<div class="red box">Lorum</div>
<div class="blue box">Ipsum</div>
<div class="blue box">Ipsum</div>
```

My nav php (I've tried to simplify what I'm doing to make things clearer here):

```
$value = "blue";
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"document.querySelector('.".$value."').classList.toggle('hover');\">Link</a>";
```

The hover action corresponds with my css linked earlier in my php and is a simple tile flip.

What ends up happening is it does it right for the first object with the class given, but not for any other objects with that class. I've tried using querySelectorAll() and getElementByClassname() but I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or I'm trying to do something that isn't really possible. Is writing a function a better way to go about this?

Any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an ID to the anchor

```
echo '<a href="#" id="link_blue">Link</a>';
```

Then add an event handler

```
$('#link_blue').on('click', function() {
    $('.blue').toggleClass('hover');
});
```